# useState in reverse when clicked again. Used as a toggle method instead of a single execution

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    }

    .change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

    .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    }
```

CSS

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './Menu.css'


export default function Menu() {

const [classes, setClasses] = useState('container')
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Click on the Menu Icon to transform it to "X":</p>
            <div className={classes} onClick={() => setClasses("container change")}>
            <div className="bar1"></div>
            <div className="bar2"></div>
            <div className="bar3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

JSX

How can I make the button work as a toggler and not just that it changes to a cross and stays like that. I want it to work like here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js

It works the one way where its turned into X, but when you click it again, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in your code that tries to make it a toggle, the button click handler just does:

```
setClasses("container change")
```

...which always sets that static value. You make it dynamic, you need to branch based on the current value; that's generally best done with a callback:

```
setClasses(classes => classes === "container" ? "container change" : "container")
```

...but with function components, hooks, and a click handler, if you're not memoizing the callback (you aren't), you could also do it directly:

```
setClasses(classes === "container" ? "container change" : "container")
```

---

FWIW, I wouldn't do it that way. `container` is always one of the classes, so I'd use a boolean:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
```

Then

```
<div className={`container ${open ? "classes" : ""}`} onClick={() => setOpen(open => !open)}>
```

Comment: Better yet would be a boolean state atom that's used to choose the class...

Comment: @AKX - LOL I was adding that as you commented. There now. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This boolean method gives me an error: Unexpected token, expected "," (11:102). I don't understand it though.

Comment: @LarsLagauw - That's because I missed out the closing `)` on the function call. Fixed now.